# Facebook live feed functionalty?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make something like facebook live feeds, for example: when someone likes something or comments on something, the page updates without refreshing it! I want to know which is the proper way to do this? regards

Answer (score 11):

Realtime updates in a web application is a hard problem because a single server handling many simultaneous long-lived TCP connections is a [hard problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

This is essentially impossible on a traditional web server like Apache + PHP because it allocates an entire OS [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)) for each incoming connection.  Threads have significant overhead (like ~2 MB of RAM just for the [stack space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation), plus whatever heap memory your application needs), so as few as a few hundred clients having your page open at the same time can bring a small server to its knees, and even an extra-large (and extra-expensive) hundred-GB-of-RAM server can only handle a few thousand concurrent connections.

Realtime communications is where [Node](http://nodejs.org/) really shines.  Its single-threaded, event-driven architecture can easily support [2,000](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/11/22/performance-benchmarking-socket-io-0-8-7-0-7-11-and-0-6-17-and-nodes-native-tcp/) concurrent connections on a commodity laptop, because each incoming connection is a small (a few kilobytes) heap allocation.  The limiting factor actually becomes the CPU and the underlying OS's TCP stack.

My recommendation is to take a look at Node – this is exactly the kind of problem it is *designed* for.  You already know JavaScript, so it's really just a matter of the API and mastering Node's async, event-driven nature.

You'll probably want to use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for your HTTP server needs and use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) for the realtime communications.

Socket.io is especially wonderful because its client-side library abstracts away all of the drudgery of cross-browser support:

- In [A-grade browsers](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), it connects to your server via [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).  This gets you a TCP socket that remains connected indefinitely, over which you can push arbitrary data at any time.
- In downlevel browsers, it uses a fallback mechanism:

  - A Flash-based transport like WebSockets, but requires Flash player (if available)
  - [AJAX long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)
  - And some more [esoteric](http://socket.io/#browser-support) fallbacks if neither of those work

Answer (score 1):

You can use long polling, yes. Or, you can start to innovate and start using HTML5's connectivity capabilities and REALTIME the sh*t out of your site. There are already several out-of-the-box solutions for that, my favourite being the [xRTML Realtime Framework](http://www.xrtml.org/demos_81.html).

Check it out

Comment: I am looking to make my own script any suggestion ? Thank you

Comment: Dependung on your experience, long polling would be a good suggestion if you're a beginner. If you are looking for something more hardcore i recommend websockets, take a look at nodeJS+socket.io